# Is it possible to import foundry anvil in rust?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, foundry, rust, arbitrage

I successfully installed and used anvil from the wsl shell.

I have some rust code, where i want to import foundry anvil instead of running from shell, cause i want to be able to control it from the app itself , reset it, fork a newblock, simulate transactions. Im trying this for 2 days already, without success.

Answer (score 2):

```
async fn anvil_mine() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
   let client = reqwest::Client::new();
   let res = client.post("http://127.0.0.1:8545")
       .json(&serde_json::json!({
           "jsonrpc": "2.0",
           "method": "anvil_mine",
           "params": [],
           "id": 1
       }))
       .send()
       .await?;
   println!("{:#?}", res.text().await?);
   Ok(())
}
```

Run

> anvil

in a terminal (default RPC url is http://127.0.0.1:8545).
Then use this code to interact with it.
You can replace "anvil_mine" by any of these:

> https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/anvil